# Hide "What's Happening" and "Who To Follow" on Twitter

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, css, twitter

Because the divs have random hash classes I can't figure out how to hide them or what to hide them with. These sections take up an insane amount of space and the content is terrible, would love to hide them.

I tried `div[aria-label="Timeline: Trending now"] {display:none;}` with [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) but either the selector or chrome extension didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I found using the uBlock Origin extension to be highly effective. To hide the "What's Happening" section first install the extension, then open the uBlock extension Dashboard controls and go to -> my filters -> and add the following custom filter

```
twitter.com##[aria-label$="trending now" i]
```

then hit-> apply

Comment: This answer worked well for removing the "What's happening"/trending section. For "Who to follow", I implemented `twitter.com##[aria-label$="who to follow" i]` in uBlock for Firefox. The data is removed. However, a gray and empty background box remains. Any recommendations to completely remove the "Who to follow" section UI element?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it still shows for me too, but it helps to add the !important flag.  Usually when I refresh the page, it goes away:

```
div[aria-label="Timeline: Trending now"] {display:none !important;}
```